# Extract day of week, day, month in string from JSON

Tags: iphone, objective-c, date, ios5, xcode4.2

I have a problem with the formatting of dates and I gently ask your help

I have a set of data in Json format including a date in the format listed below, example:

```
DateEvent ":" 02/24/2012 00:00:00 "
```

From this date I extract format string, locating the language, the following values​​:

```
Day of week: Friday (Italian)
Day: 24
Month: January (Italian)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a NSDateFormatter to translate the string to a NSDate object. Then use NSDateComponents with that date to get the values you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I solved it with "NSDateComponents", I found a good example:

source:[Example][1]


  [1]: http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/476-How-to-extract-current-year-month-and-day-from-an-NSDate-with-NSCalendar-NSDateComponents-and-NSDateFormatter